# When you turn on Voice Over in an ios device, and cannot scroll in a worklight hybrid application, is there anyone who met this before?

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, voiceover

IOS has a ability for disabled person. And when you turn on Voice Over in an ios device, we have a hybrid ios app written by worklight6.2

in the app, page cannot scroll, is there anyone who met this before?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide a sample of code if you want some specific help here.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this...

I create an app with some elements and lots of spacing between them.
It wasn't easy to scroll with VoiceOver enabled, but it does scroll.

You'll need to provide something tangible to test to progress further.

Comment: I found that is because that we are using iscroll to deal with scroll refresh.  Do you have any good idea about it? voice over + scroll refresh

Comment: I do not. I suggest that you will contact the iScroll team.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that when you turn on voice over, scrolling on the device begins to work differently. To scroll you must use three fingers.